# How to rename entire java package name in Eclipse so that its all occurences gets renamed?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, gdata, gdata-api

I want to rename entire package and it's all ocurences includeing package name and imports, change in eclipse.

For example com.google.gdata.client and its classes to com.xyz.google.gdata.client and its all occurences.

Actually, I want to customize gdata-core.1.47.jar source code as per my requirement. First thing I need to do is to change the package structure as per my requirements. But when I followed the above mentioned steps, some more imports were automatically added

For example before refctor, 
For class com.google.api.gbase.client has following import

```
import com.google.gdata.util.common.xml.XmlWriter;
import com.google.gdata.data.Extension;
import com.google.gdata.data.ExtensionProfile;
import com.google.gdata.data.AttributeHelper;
import com.google.gdata.data.ExtensionDescription;
import com.google.gdata.util.ParseException;
import com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser;
```

But after after rename it to com.google.gdata.client  to com.xyz.google.gdata.client it add some more imports like below,

```
import com.google.api.gbase.client.AddValueHandler;
import com.google.api.gbase.client.AttributeHistogram;
import com.google.api.gbase.client.GoogleBaseAttributeId;
import com.google.api.gbase.client.GoogleBaseAttributeType;
import com.google.api.gbase.client.GoogleBaseEntry;
import com.google.api.gbase.client.UniqueValue;
import com.google.gdata.util.XmlWriter;
import com.xyz.google.gdata.data.AttributeHelper;
import com.xyz.google.gdata.data.Extension;
import com.xyz.google.gdata.data.ExtensionDescription;
import com.xyz.google.gdata.data.ExtensionProfile;
import com.xyz.google.gdata.util.ParseException;
import com.xyz.google.gdata.util.XmlParser;
```

Answer (score 5):

In the Project Explorer, right click the package name and choose Refactor->Rename.

Comment: I followed that steps, But it includes some extra imports which is not present in original code.

Comment: Actually, I want to customize gdata-core.1.47.jar source code as per my requirement. First thing I need to do is to change the package structure as per my requirements. But when I followed the above mentioned steps, some more imports were automatically added.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "more imports"? Are packages that were not imported before are now imported? That seems unlikely to happen.

Comment: Yes That's unlikely things happend. For example before rename it has only 4 import, But after refoctor it import 3 more package.

Comment: Can you provide an example?